# Button onClick in a menu prefab doesn't work

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I don't seem to be able to make a reference to a Button inside a menu prefab.

My menu prefab consists of a panel and the panel has 4 buttons.

I added

```
public GameObject prefabMenu;
```

in my code and drag and dropped the prefab in the Unity Editor to it.

When my scene is starting (`Start()` method) I instantiate this prefab into a GameObject like this:

```
panelMenu = Instantiate(prefabMenu, canvas.transform);
```

after that I try to refer one of the buttons with this line and set an `onClick` listener:

```
btnResume = panelMenu.transform.Find("BtnResume").GetComponent<Button>();
btnResume.onClick.AddListener(() => Log.I("Working"));
```

The log method however doesn't not get called when I click on the button (I checked and the `btnResume` is not null).

I appreciate any help on this. Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have the Eventsystem in your scene, correct?

Comment: You don't have Raycast on the UI stopping the button from being clicked, right?

Comment: @Zibelas No, I didn't have. I added it and now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- first check is your event system object present in the Hierarchy if yes then create a button check its working or not if working fine then its your button problem either it can be due Raycast or some other UI object over that button.

2- second try is that assign a function from editor to that button if its working then your event subscribing (onclick event) is in problem..

Answer (score -1):

To have click events in a prefab try to use `IPointerClickHandler` interface.